# Caching Facet Queries

Tags: ravendb, faceted-search

Just tracked down a bug relating to what appears to be a facet query being cached in RavenDB.

I found the line of code that sets aggresive caching but only for the given session. In this session, it appears the code is only getting a 'FacetSetup' doc and not executing a query on facets. However, I have confirmed that when the given line of code is commented out, I receive the current facet count and when I reinstate the comment and make an update, I receive the stale facet count.

My question is: What does this line actually tell Raven to cache?

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the facet names from the main facet document.
    /// That way, we know all the possible facets to query over.
    /// We will execute a facet query for each facet in the FacetSetup
    /// </summary>
    private IEnumerable<string> GetFacetNamesFromFacetSetup(IDocumentStore store, string facetDocumentName)
    {
        IList<string> facetFromDocument = new List<string>();
        using (IDocumentSession docSession = store.OpenSession())
        {
            //The line below here!!    
            docSession.Advanced.DocumentStore.AggressivelyCacheFor(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30));
            FacetSetup facetSetup = docSession.Load<FacetSetup>(facetDocumentName);
            foreach (Facet facet in facetSetup.Facets)
            {
                facetFromDocument.Add(facet.Name);
            }
        }
        return facetFromDocument;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AggressivelyCacheFor is global for the document store.
And it returns an IDisposable.
Until you dispose it, all operations will be eagerly cached.